# How to group decimal places as well?

Tags: c++

I want to get `x = 1,234,567,890.098,765,432,1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;


struct separated : numpunct<char>
{
    string do_grouping() const { return "\03"; }
};


int main()
{
    const double x = 1234567890.0987654321;
    locale our_local(cout.getloc(), new separated);
    cout.imbue(our_local);
    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(10);
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `x = 1,234,567,890.0987654321`

Expected output: `x = 1,234,567,890.098,765,432,1`

It will be much better if you can make it more general as follows,

- `x = 1'234'567'890.098'765'432'1`
- `x = 1_234_567_890.098_765_432_1`

The decimal point is dot (US-EN).

## Question

How to group decimal places as well?

## Edit

`x` is of type `double` and not a literal string.

Comment: Are there any countries which use than convention?

Comment: @Jarod42: No need to stick to culture because it is just for personal use to ease readability in debug mode.

Comment: locale grouping only applies to the numbers on the left side of the decimal point, never to the numbers on the right side.  See the format definitions of [`std::numpunct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct) on cppreference.com.  You will have to split the floating-point number into its integral and fractional components and output them separately so you can apply grouping to both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an algorithm:

Create a function that takes the number to convert as its parameter.  Convert that number to a string.  Scan the string for a decimal point (while being aware of the possibility for non-numeric results like infinity or indefinite).  If found, process the remainder of the string, inserting your separator character after every third digit, stopping when you reach the end of the string or a non-digit (for example, an `E` to designate an exponent).  Return this string.

As an additional exercise, create a version of this function that can be passed to `cout` as a manipulator.