# C++ print with digit grouping to the *right* of decimal point

Tags: c++, formatting, iostream

I want to print doubles so that their fractional part is formatted as follows:

- `0.123`
- `0.123 4`
- `0.123 45`
- `0.123 456`
- `0.123 456 7`

I am aware that I can inherit from `std::numpunct` and overload `do_grouping()` and `do_thousands_sep()`, but these functions seem to only affect spacing to the **left** of the decimal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

struct fmt : public std::numpunct<char> {
    string_type do_grouping() const { return "\3"; }
    char_type do_thousands_sep() const { return ' '; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new fmt));
    std::cout.precision(10);
    std::cout << 12345.12345 << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

`12 345.12345`

Is there an easy way of automatically adding spacing to the **right** of the decimal?

**Edit:**

In [How to group decimal places as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660511/how-to-group-decimal-places-as-well) the only answer suggest the asker write their own function. My question is whether there is an *easy* way (like another `std::numpunct` function to overload). I am aware that I could write my own function, but I'd like confirmation that it is necessary to do so.